# A distribution of maximum of sums if add to the minimal

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, integer-sequences

Consider a vector of $n$ integer variables with initial values of 0. Each step we take random $w_i\thicksim NB(q, l)$ (independent randon values with the same negative binomial distribution) and add it to the variable with the minimal current value, even cases go to the leftmost of the equal variables. What is the CDF of the maximal value in the vector at a given step?

Comment: This is what stochastic simulation is for.

Comment: But it looks like a common optimization case, may there be an analytic expression?